# Android : Location Update in Mapview takes to long even tough Location is found

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location, locationlistener

I have a problem with my Location Listener in a MapView Application.
Especially there is a Problem with the time, my actual Position will be painted on a Map.

I attached two listeners to my MapView. The first one waits for a signal from the Network and the second one from the GPS. At the beginning of the Listener Implementation I get the Last Known Location to reduce the Time while other providers search a position.

My LocationListner in the MapView is called as followed:

```
public void locationManager(){

    mLocationUpdateHandlerGPS       = new LocationUpdateHandler();
    mLocationUpdateHandlerNetwork   = new LocationUpdateHandler();

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //-------Check if Network is available-----
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationUpdateHandlerNetwork);

    //-------Check if GPS is available---------
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, mLocationUpdateHandlerGPS);


}
```

The LocationUpdateHandler.class where i implemented the Listener looks like this:

```
public class LocationUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

        //Log Actual Position
        Log.v(TAG, "Actual Postion // Get Latitude: " + lat);           
        Log.v(TAG, "Actual Postion // Get Longitude: " + lng);

        mMyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        Log.v(TAG, "Enable Location returns: "+mMyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation());

        mMyLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMapView.getController().animateTo(
                        mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

After the Map starts i check the Log Output from the DDMS and can see that the Location is get in Time.

```
08-29 14:50:16.136: VERBOSE/GeoTagMapActivity(7300): Running Activity GeoTagMapActivity
08-29 14:50:20.691: VERBOSE/GeoTagMapActivity(7300): Enable Location returns: true
08-29 14:50:20.691: VERBOSE/GeoTagMapActivity(7300): Actual Postion // Get Latitude: *******
08-29 14:50:20.691: VERBOSE/GeoTagMapActivity(7300): Actual Postion // Get Longitude: *******
```

Nevertheless i takes another 2 - 5 minutes until the Position will drawn on the Map.

I have no idea where's the Problem.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This may not answer your question, but I know that getting a [real] fix takes a couple of minutes sometimes. My most recent app uses GPS, and it's frustrating because I know when I start it, if I have not gotten a fix recently it will take a few minutes.

Comment: mMyLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMapView.getController().animateTo(
                        mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
            }
        }); instead of this. and just write       mMapView.getController().animateTo(
                        mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation()); try it.

Comment: Hello @Jack thanks for your answer. But, I'm a little bit confused now. As is see in the log files it takes only 4 seconds till the app catches a position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MyLocationOverlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) is a helper class of Google Maps for Android. It does it's own location acquiring, more specifically it uses GPS to do it.

Since you call `runOnFirstFix(runnable)` it waits to get a GPS fix before executing your code. This can sometimes (especially indoor) take minutes. Hence the delay. It's also entirely possible to acquire network-based location, but not GPS position (especially indoors), so in this case your code would never be executed (except if `MyLocationOverlay` falls back to network  provider after timeout - this isn't explained anywhere).

The position that you see in the logs are positions that you acquire via network location provider (wifi and cell network locations).

Just remove `runOnFirstFix()` as @user370305 suggested in comments.

Comment: Hello Peter and @user370305. Thanks a lot for our answers. After I remove runOnFirstFix() and set the initial Location with MapController.animateTo(GeoPoint) it runs very smooth :).